# AngularJS JSON scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make my Angular controller more generic in the way it handles JSON array of objects.

Currently I have the following defined:

```
 $scope.Data = [];
```

and I pull across the data in my template like:

```
ng-repeat="item in Data.category[3].values
```

My JSON looks like:

```
 "category": [{
"name": "cat1",
"behaviour": "normal",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "define",
    "count": 6
}]
}, {
"name": "cat2",
"behaviour": "normal",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "type",
    "count": 6
}]
}, {
"name": "Company",
"behaviour": "multi-select",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "VW",
    "count": 4
}, {
    "label": "Renault",
    "count": 1
}, {
    "label": "Fiat",
    "count": 1
}]
}, {
"name": "Make",
"behaviour": "multi-select",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "Gold",
    "count": 3
}]
}, {
"name": "Color",
"behaviour": "normal",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "White",
    "count": 3
}, {
    "label": "Blue",
    "count": 2
}, {
    "label": "Green",
    "count": 1
}]
}]
```

What I'm trying to do is rather than access a specific index with:

```
 Data.category[3].values
```

I'd like to loop through category and grab a list of index items so I can use like:

```
Data.category[Color].values
```

where Color is found in the list, and I can bring back the values for that specific element, is that possible?

Comment: color is an attribute in values or in category?

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to do the same as you are doing with category now, e.g. making it something like: Data.category.color.values?

Comment: learn how to use `Array.prototype.filter()`

Comment: @charlietfl possible using anglar pipe filter

Comment: @pankajparkar depends on what is being done. Use case isn't very clear

Comment: @charlietfl I thought mine would be right..hopefully..lets see what OP want

Comment: color is an attribute in values, within the category array

Answer (score 1):

You would use `filter` instead, you can also pass `Color` value dynamically through scope.

**Markup**

```
ng-repeat="item in (Data.category| {name: 'Color'}: true)[0].values
```

**Update**

You could pass `Color` variable dynamically through another scope variable, like `$scope.color = 'Color'` so the ng-repeat will become

**Html**

```
ng-repeat="item in (Data.category| {name: color}: true)[0].values
```

Comment: I think this would be the best for my usecase, as I want to specify name:value, however at the moment once I change, I don't seem to get anything back?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want but if you need to display value in function of color attribute you could do this in your controller:

```
      $scope.dataToDisplay = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.Data.length ; i++){
     {
        if($scope.Data.color == 'yourcolor') {
              $scope.dataToDisplay.push($scope.Data[i].values)
           }
      }
```

And in your HTML you just display dataToDisplay